# How can I make the horizontal bar hidden and make left and right buttons to scroll horizontally?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I make the horizontal bar hidden and make left and right buttons to scroll horizontally?

Also the scrolling should be enabled for mobiles (touch enabled).
I've created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/soulsurfer/muL9mrL1/) of the markup I'm working on.  Thanks a lot.

```
<div class="ui grid container r-feat-prod-row">
<div class="row">
  <!--featured column starts-->
  <div class="left floaded fourteen wide column">
    <div class="ui container">
      <div class="ui segment r-feat-col">
        <h4 class="ui horizontal divider header">Featured Category</h4>
        <!--featured products starts-->
        <div class="scroll">
          <div class="r-content">

            <div class="r-prod-card">
              <div class="blurring dimmable image ">
                <div class="ui dimmer">
                  <div class="content">
                    <div class="r-feat-header">
                      <div class="ui inverted">Product long title second line Product long title Product...</div>
                      <div class="ui divider"></div>
                      <div class="meta">
                        <span class="r-feat-header-price inverted">USD 100,000.00</span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <img class="i-feat-img" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/upload.uxpin/files/209268/214371/watch.png">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="i-prod-card">
              <div class="blurring dimmable image ">
                <div class="ui dimmer">
                  <div class="content">
                    <div class="rfeat-header">
                      <div class="ui inverted">Product long title second line Product long title Product...</div>
                      <div class="ui divider"></div>
                      <div class="meta">
                        <span class="r-feat-header-price inverted">USD 100,000.00</span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <img class="i-feat-img" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/upload.uxpin/files/209268/214371/watch.png">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="i-prod-card">
              <div class="blurring dimmable image ">
                <div class="ui dimmer">
                  <div class="content">
                    <div class="i-feat-header">
                      <div class="ui inverted">Product long title second line Product long title Product...</div>
                      <div class="ui divider"></div>
                      <div class="meta">
                        <span class="i-feat-header-price inverted">MVR 100,000.00</span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <img class="i-feat-img" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/upload.uxpin/files/209268/214371/watch.png">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="i-prod-card">
              <div class="blurring dimmable image ">
                <div class="ui dimmer">
                  <div class="content">
                    <div class="i-feat-header">
                      <div class="ui inverted">Product long title second line Product long title Product...</div>
                      <div class="ui divider"></div>
                      <div class="meta">
                        <span class="r-feat-header-price inverted">USD 100,000.00</span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <img class="r-feat-img" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/upload.uxpin/files/209268/214371/watch.png">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="i-prod-card">
              <div class="blurring dimmable image ">
                <div class="ui dimmer">
                  <div class="content">
                    <div class="rfeat-header">
                      <div class="ui inverted">Product long title second line Product long title Product...</div>
                      <div class="ui divider"></div>
                      <div class="meta">
                        <span class="r-feat-header-price inverted">USD 100,000.00</span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <img class="r-feat-img" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/upload.uxpin/files/209268/2143s1/watch.png">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="rprod-card">
              <div class="blurring dimmable image ">
                <div class="ui dimmer">
                  <div class="content">
                    <div class="r-feat-header">
                      <div class="ui inverted">Product long title second line Product long title Product...</div>
                      <div class="ui divider"></div>
                      <div class="meta">
                        <span class="r-feat-header-price inverted">USD 100,000.00</span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <img class="r-feat-img" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/upload.uxpin/files/209268/21s71/watch.png">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="r-prod-card">
              <div class="blurring dimmable image ">
                <div class="ui dimmer">
                  <div class="content">
                    <div class="r-feat-header">
                      <div class="ui inverted">Product long title second line Product long title Product...</div>
                      <div class="ui divider"></div>
                      <div class="meta">
                        <span class="r-feat-header-price inverted">USD 100,000.00</span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <img class="i-feat-img" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/upload.uxpin/files/209268/214371/watch.png">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="r-prod-card">
              <div class="blurring dimmable image ">
                <div class="ui dimmer">
                  <div class="content">
                    <div class="r-feat-header">
                      <div class="ui inverted">Product long title second line Product long title Product...</div>
                      <div class="ui divider"></div>
                      <div class="meta">
                        <span class="r-feat-header-price inverted">USD 100,000.00</span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <img class="i-feat-img" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/upload.uxpin/files/209268/2s4371/watch.png">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <!--featured products ends-->
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- right side 300x250 ad column starts-->
  <div class="one wide column">
    <div class="ui medium rectangle test ad r-ad-300" data-text="Advertising seems to be blocked by your browser.
     It is fine, but please keep in mind that advertising helps us to host the website. If you find these ads intrusive or inappropriate, feel free to contact us.">

    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- right side 300x250 ad column ends-->
  <!--featured column ends-->
</div>
```

Comment: What horizontal bar? The scroll bar?

Comment: Where are the left and right buttons?

Comment: @divy3993 there is no right and left button at the moment, I need help adding right and left button too.

Comment: @hopkins-matt yes the horizontal scroll bar

Comment: Did you check http://www.menucool.com/horizontal/javascript-menu ? Or http://hugogiraudel.com/2013/08/23/scroll-overflow-menu/ ?

Comment: @Prusse no? what does it has to do with this question?

Comment: Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bpq8w50w/ Can't see the horizontal scroll bar though...

Comment: @robinmckenzie I have no idea what you even did there!? I see you copy pasted my html markup only. That's all I see. maybe you posted a wrong link?

Comment: My mistake - didn't see your fiddle above the textarea.

Comment: i don't know why my animate isn't working but maybe you can get it to work http://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/qwraew4x/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since not all browsers allow you to style the scroll bar, I have used `overflow-y:hidden;` on the parent to hide the scroll bar. You can style the buttons however you want. I just put them at the bottom.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hopkins_matt/muL9mrL1/1/

**CSS:**

```
/* featured column */

.ui.segment.i-feat-col {
    overflow-y:hidden;
}

.i-feat-prod-row {
    margin-top: 30px !important;
}
h4.ui.horizontal.divider.header {
    color: #6CAF2B;
}
.i-feat-col {
    height: 250px !important;
}
.i-prod-card {
    width: 170px;
    height: 170px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 0 rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.15);
    margin: 0.5rem 1em;
    margin-top: auto;
    padding: 1em 1em;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.15);
    top: 6px;
}
div.scroll {
    height: calc(100% + 10px);
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling-x: touch;
}
div.scroll:hover {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
.i-content {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.i-feat-header {
    text-transform: capitalize;
    font-size: 12px;
    white-space: initial !important;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 17px;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    padding-right: 11px;
    padding-left: 11px;
    clear: right;
}
.i-feat-header-price {
    color: #F44336;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 15px;
}
.i-feat-img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 140px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
.dimmable {
    position: absolute;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$(function () {
    $('.i-prod-card .image').dimmer({
        on: 'hover'
    });
});

function scrollHoz(dir) {
    if (dir == 'L') {
        $('.scroll').animate({
            scrollLeft: "-=" + 250 + "px"
        });
    } else if (dir == 'R') {
        $('.scroll').animate({
            scrollLeft: "+=" + 250 + "px"
        });
    }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="ui grid container i-feat-prod-row">
    <div class="row">
        <!--featured column starts-->
        <div class="left floaded fourteen wide column">
            <div class="ui container">
                <div class="ui segment i-feat-col">
                     <h4 class="ui horizontal divider header">Featured Category</h4>

                    <!--featured products starts-->
                    <div class="scroll">
                        <div class="i-content">
                            <div class="i-prod-card">
                                <div class="blurring dimmable image ">
                                    <div class="ui dimmer">
                                        <div class="content">
                                            <div class="i-feat-header">
                                                <div class="ui inverted">Product long title second line Product long title Product...</div>
                                                <div class="ui divider"></div>
                                                <div class="meta"> <span class="i-feat-header-price inverted">MVR 100,000.00</span>

                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <img class="i-feat-img" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/upload.uxpin/files/209268/214371/watch.png">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="i-prod-card">
                                <div class="blurring dimmable image ">
                                    <div class="ui dimmer">
                                        <div class="content">
                                            <div class="i-feat-header">
                                                <div class="ui inverted">Product long title second line Product long title Product...</div>
                                                <div class="ui divider"></div>
                                                <div class="meta"> <span class="i-feat-header-price inverted">MVR 100,000.00</span>

                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <img class="i-feat-img" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/upload.uxpin/files/209268/214371/watch.png">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="i-prod-card">
                                <div class="blurring dimmable image ">
                                    <div class="ui dimmer">
                                        <div class="content">
                                            <div class="i-feat-header">
                                                <div class="ui inverted">Product long title second line Product long title Product...</div>
                                                <div class="ui divider"></div>
                                                <div class="meta"> <span class="i-feat-header-price inverted">MVR 100,000.00</span>

                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <img class="i-feat-img" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/upload.uxpin/files/209268/214371/watch.png">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="i-prod-card">
                                <div class="blurring dimmable image ">
                                    <div class="ui dimmer">
                                        <div class="content">
                                            <div class="i-feat-header">
                                                <div class="ui inverted">Product long title second line Product long title Product...</div>
                                                <div class="ui divider"></div>
                                                <div class="meta"> <span class="i-feat-header-price inverted">MVR 100,000.00</span>

                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <img class="i-feat-img" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/upload.uxpin/files/209268/214371/watch.png">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="i-prod-card">
                                <div class="blurring dimmable image ">
                                    <div class="ui dimmer">
                                        <div class="content">
                                            <div class="i-feat-header">
                                                <div class="ui inverted">Product long title second line Product long title Product...</div>
                                                <div class="ui divider"></div>
                                                <div class="meta"> <span class="i-feat-header-price inverted">MVR 100,000.00</span>

                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <img class="i-feat-img" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/upload.uxpin/files/209268/214371/watch.png">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="i-prod-card">
                                <div class="blurring dimmable image ">
                                    <div class="ui dimmer">
                                        <div class="content">
                                            <div class="i-feat-header">
                                                <div class="ui inverted">Product long title second line Product long title Product...</div>
                                                <div class="ui divider"></div>
                                                <div class="meta"> <span class="i-feat-header-price inverted">MVR 100,000.00</span>

                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <img class="i-feat-img" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/upload.uxpin/files/209268/214371/watch.png">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="i-prod-card">
                                <div class="blurring dimmable image ">
                                    <div class="ui dimmer">
                                        <div class="content">
                                            <div class="i-feat-header">
                                                <div class="ui inverted">Product long title second line Product long title Product...</div>
                                                <div class="ui divider"></div>
                                                <div class="meta"> <span class="i-feat-header-price inverted">MVR 100,000.00</span>

                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <img class="i-feat-img" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/upload.uxpin/files/209268/214371/watch.png">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="i-prod-card">
                                <div class="blurring dimmable image ">
                                    <div class="ui dimmer">
                                        <div class="content">
                                            <div class="i-feat-header">
                                                <div class="ui inverted">Product long title second line Product long title Product...</div>
                                                <div class="ui divider"></div>
                                                <div class="meta"> <span class="i-feat-header-price inverted">MVR 100,000.00</span>

                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <img class="i-feat-img" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/upload.uxpin/files/209268/214371/watch.png">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--featured products ends-->
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- right side 300x250 ad column starts-->
        <div class="one wide column">
            <div class="ui medium rectangle test ad i-ad-300" data-text="Advertising seems to be blocked by your browser.
         It is fine, but please keep in mind that advertising helps us to host the website. If you find these ads intrusive or inappropriate, feel free to contact us.">
                <iframe class="i-frame-ad" src="http://admanager.ibay.com.mv/show.php?z=57" width="300" height="250" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" hspace="0" vspace="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- right side 300x250 ad column ends-->
        <!--featured column ends-->
    </div>
</div>
<button onclick="scrollHoz('L')">Left</button>
<button onclick="scrollHoz('R')">Right</button>
```